# (Objective C) Obtain CFstringRef from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ftp, automatic-ref-counting

I have an NSMutableArray that was downloaded via FTP. The elements in the array are [CFFTPStream resource constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003359-CH4-CFStreamHTTPandHTTPSProxyKeyConstants) that are of type CFStringRef.

I would like to create a String from the "kCFFTPResourceName" constant. However being new to Objective C and iphone development I am struggling.

Everything that I have done has resulted in ARC throwing a fit or errors like:

```
2013-01-03 15:31:44.874 Street Light Reporter[1382:11603] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e1e930
2013-01-03 15:31:44.875 Street Light Reporter[1382:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e1e930'
```

My most recent attempt is:
    CFStringRef *c = [ar objectAtIndex:4];
which doesnt work for the following two reasons:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CFStringRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFString **') with an expression of type 'id'
```

AND

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'CFStringRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFString **') is disallowed with ARC
```

I have tried all sorts of typecasting and messing around with (__bridge) and whatnot and I have had no luck.

Can anybody help me out here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  Show us a dump of the source JSON string (at least the first 50 chars or so) or an NSLog of the object you got back from your JSON decoder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors here: the first and the most severe one is that your `ar` object is a `NSDictionary` not a `NSArray`. That's why performing

```
CFStringRef *c = [ar objectAtIndex:4];
```

you are getting a `NSInvalidArgumentException`. `objectAtIndex:` is a method of `NSArray` that you are sending to a `NSdictionary` instance.

The second error is the cast. As Fernando already pointed out, you need to cast it using the `__bridge` keyword like follows.

```
CFStringRef c = (__bridge CFStringRef)([ar objectAtIndex:4]);
```

so that ARC will know that you are now treating that object as a C pointer.

Note also that `CFStringRef` is defined as

```
typedef const struct __CFString * CFStringRef;
```

so it's already a pointer and you have to get rid of the `*`.

Comment: Very thorough. However, the plain `__bridge` _doesn't_ transfer ownership; the underlying object will still be managed by ARC. You need `__bridge_retained` to take responsibility.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're absolutely right. I got confused with `__bridge_transfer`.

Comment: I always get confused, too. I had to go look it up to be sure before I commented.

Comment: I am confused as to how ar is not an array. I created it using: `NSMutableArray *ar = [self.listEntries objectAtIndex:i];` where listentries is an array or arrays. This is in a for loop.

Comment: Ooooooh man. listEntries is an array of dictionaries not an array of arrays. I guess this is one of those "head->keyboard" moments. It works, thanks man.

Answer (score 5):

CFStringRef is a pointer already, you don't need the star. Also, you can cast CFStringRef to NSString and it will work fine and will be easier to work with. This is called toll free bridging. If you still need the CFStringRef:

ARC:

```
CFStringRef c = (__bridge CFStringRef)([ar objectAtIndex:4]);
```

Non arc

```
CFStringRef c = (CFStringRef)([ar objectAtIndex:4]);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that **poor abandoned hated non-ARC solution.**

Comment: It compiles, but once I step over that line, the app crashes with this:  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79cd1e0'`

Comment: Well, that's because your "ar" is an NSDictionary and not an NSArray, so something is wrong in your parsing and it's not in the code you posted

Comment: @0nyx - The problem is presumably that you downloaded and decoded JSON and what it represents is a JSON "object", which maps to an NSDictionary.  This problem has nothing to do with ARC.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you get an CFDictionary back and not an array.
The constants you linked to are keys for the dictionary, with which you can access the values.